# android Custom dialog translucent margin

Tags: android, dialog, themes

How can I customize the look of the translucent area around a popup dialog?  That is, the area showing the underlying activity.

The popup activity is being started with

```
Intent intent = new Intent (app, MyPopup.class);
app.startActivityForResult (intent, requestCode);
```

where app is the current activity.

The top level of the XML file is a ScrollView.  I've tried setting the background there, but the setting is ignored.  As well, I've tried adjusting the margins, but those are ignored as well. (NB - I now realize that margins apply only to LinearLayout; ignore that issue, please.) For example:

```
<ScrollView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_margin="20dp"
  android:maxWidth="200dp" >
```

Above, the margin and maxWidth are ignored.

And, I've tried setting up a custom style:

```
<style name="PopupTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Dialog">
  <item name="android:background">#FFF2F2F2</item>
  <item name="android:textColor">#FF000000</item>
  <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>"
  <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
  <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">false</item>
  <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/dialog_background</item>
</style>
```

In this style, the backgroundDimEnabled does make a difference - it allows the originating acitivity to show in full brightness.  However the other attributes seem to be ignored.  The fact that so many settings I've tried have no effect leads me to believe that either I'm missing some important "lynch pin" setting or Google hard coded too much behavior for these settings to work.

I could add another layer to all my popups, where the layer is full screen and does the translucency the way I want, having he true dialog be placed on top of that.  I'd prefer to not do a workaround if there's a proper way to do what I want.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

there is a problem with the ScrollView as it extends from FrameLayout because of this you can not apply margins to it. My hint of what you can do is create a LinearLayout within the ScrollView and apply margins to it.

something like this:

```
<ScrollView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="top"
                    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: What do you mean "there is a problem with ScrollView"?

Comment: with respect to margins, in your case.

Comment: Right.  Margins should apply only to LinearLayout.  Well, then the margins are a red herring to the problem at hand.